# How to find value without comment?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a file with string and some string with comment

```
myapps:
- name: app1
- name: app2

# - name app3
# - name app4
```

when I search for app3 I don't want to get any result, because it is in comment

I read the file to data and the appName could be app3 or app4

```
 if (data.indexOf(`- name: ${appName}`) < 0) {
     ....
   }
```

What do I need to change in case of app1 and app2 to exist in data and in case of app3 and app4 should not exist because of the comments

Comment: This won't find app3 because `# name app3` is not `- name: app3` right?

Comment: Though Praveen is to the point in comment, try `/^[^#].*- name: app\d/i.test(data)`

Comment: I updated the name sorry I missed the - before and it find  the app3

Comment: @rajesh - where do I need to add your exp ? could you explain it ?

Comment: This looks like YAML. Why not use a YAML parser?

Comment: @user1365697 Still the same. I guess you meant `# - name: app3` and the other one.

Comment: It is the yank because the yaml could exist comments

Comment: @praveen yes you write I just want to check if there is comment before and then don’t to check this value

Comment: Split to rows, then exclude rows starting with `#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using a multine regex.

```
// Use ^ in combination with "m" modifier to match start of line
const regex = new RegExp(`^- name: ${appName}`, 'gm');
const matches = data.match(regex);

if (matches && matches.length > 0) {
   // Insert code
}
```